# Localhost htaccess code not working on real server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had written the .htaccess code below for my website while I was developing using wampserver (localhost).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /category.php?id=name&phrase=something to /name/something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?id=([^&]+)&phrase=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Cleans up all the article, and wrestler pages
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]+)/?$ wrestler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# For the redirecion of related topics links on wrestler profile pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&phrase=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I just brought the website live on a real server, and I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error."

Am I supposed to make some changes to the code when going from localhost to the real server?  Please help out guys.

Comment: It's possible that `FollowSymLinks` is not an allowed option or that `mod_rewrite` is disabled. Have you tried commenting out the `Options +FollowSymLinks` line to start with?

Comment: I just tried that, and it didn't help. I'm so confused.

Comment: What is the associated error being written to your Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

The odds are very good that this is an issue with a disabled module on the live server. You should be able to access your server logs and see the exact line throwing this error, but I'm willing to bet that it's a disabled module (in this case, mod_rewrite might not be enabled for your server--I've had several hosts with this issue).

Depending on your host and the level of configuration you have over the server, you may need to contact support and ask them to look into the logs for you.